# Axiomatic system that differentiates between straight lines and curved lines

Tags: formal-systems, axiomatic-geometry

I was thinking about a formal system that involves a set of primitives along with a property that, when applied to the model of planar one-dimensional objects, can distinguish between straight lines and curved lines. The system I came up with was:

```
Primitive terms:
     a. 2-D Environment
     b. Direction (also 2-D based)
     c. Opposite direction
     d. Equal direction
     e. 1-D object
     f. Point on 1-D object
     g. Continuous
Definition of "Straight Line":
     - A "straight line" is any continuous 1-D object in a 2-D environment for which the direction of the object at any (arbitrary) point on the object is either equal or opposite to the direction of the object at any other (arbitrary) point on it.
```

Now, my question is **can this definition be considered to be a necessary and sufficient criterion for being a straight line**, when all the primitive terms are assumed to have the meanings that we imply when we use the terms in real life? Also, **can any term be considered redundant for the system**?

All suggestions regarding changes for developing the system are welcome.

EDIT: As commented by @Gribouillis, there is a problem in the system, as line segments are also classified as straight lines according to the definition I came up with.

Comment: The definition also applies to line segments instead of lines.

Comment: @Gribouillis Ah yes. Hadn’t thought of that. Can it be amended by saying that for every point on the object we can associate 2 directions with it?

Comment: It would still apply to an open segment (segment without the ends)

Comment: @EricNathanStucky could you suggest any means to correct the definition so that it truly catches the “geometric sense” while still retaining enough generality to be extendible to other models, as in the example you gave?

Comment: @EricNathanStucky no problem. By the way your example was quite good food-for-thought

Comment: So the example that I gave was way out of line because of the provision that the primitive terms have to line up in some way with their common-use meanings, which I missed on first reading. But I would suggest looking into other axiom systems for geometries e.g. Hilbert or even Euclid. The important thing is that these systems also describe the *relations* between the relevant primitives (and defined terms). You can of course still try to retain nonstandard interpretations like mine, but things like "any two points define a unique line" go a long way toward boxing them out.

Comment: @Gribouillis can you think of any way to amend the system without creating any new primitive like “finitely sized”, that is, using the primitives already there?

Comment: @EricNathanStucky by “relations” do you mean some kind of inferences using the described objects?

Comment: @EricNathanStucky then by relations you were referring to the axioms that define the “primitive truths” or how the primitives are connected together? And does building this kind of axiomatic system _always_ mean removing all the extrinsically implied meaning from the primitive terms? That is, what remains are just some primitive symbols with no meaning of themselves, just the meanings defined by the axiomatic relationships?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148716/discussion-between-eric-nathan-stucky-and-soham-saha).